# How do I rollup a hundred nagios service checks to a single check?

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I'm monitoring a service via check_nrpe to hundreds of boxes. Whenever this service goes bad, typically every box goes bad and get flooded with notifications/text msgs.

Any suggestions on how or what to use to roll all this up in to a single check?

Answer (score 5):

Seems like this would be a good case to utilize the Nagios dependency system. Make all the hundreds of checks dependent on this one check_nrpe, and that should suppress all the extraneous notifications.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other fine suggestions given, if you really just literally want to create a new additional check that fires when any of a set of checks fires, try check_service.pl http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Others/Check-many-services/details.

Answer (score 0):

If that's the case first make sure you're monitoring the right thing.  If for instance the problem is that a switch fails and all you're doing is monitoring the hosts attached to it you'll get a bunch of host down alerts.  Second use dependencies.  This allows nagios to notify you on the switch failure and ignore all the hosts down alerts behind it.